# Adding contribution_id or transaction_id to Receipt

Tags: receipts, system-workflow-messages

I've searched and can't find anything that works.

How do I add the Contribution ID and/or transaction_id to a receipt (Online and Offline)?

What I'm looking for is a way to easily find a contribution if a donor calls inquiring. I can ask them the contribution id and then search. Then I noticed that there's not a way to search by contribution id but there is by transaction id. However, transaction id isn't automatically created unless it's an online credit card donation. If I process a check or cash then it doesn't create a transaction id. Any suggestions on some options?

What do other's use on their receipts as the id?

Answer (score 2):

{$contributionID} should work ....

Comment: That worked but I want to see what other's have done.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I noticed that there's not a way to search by contribution id but
>   there is by transaction id.

You can search for Contributions and use "Invoice Number" - which constitutes of Invoice prefix + **Contribution ID**.

For Example: Invoice Number: INV1234 -> Contribution ID: 1234

(You can set that invoice prefix under administer-CiviContribute, where you can activate invoicing.)

The token {contributions.contribution_id} should be useful.